# Different type of column

Tags: database-design

Maybe the title is misleading but I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do.

I'm building an e-commerce site. I have my products and my order.
I want add constrains on how the order will be deliver to the customer depending on each product.

For example if I sell a big and fragile product I want to restrict it from being send with courier, the customer should only have the option to take it from the shop.
Or a specific product can only be sent to limited countries.

I thought I could create an extra table related to products.

[image]

That way I could know which types of constrains each product have.
And I have no limitation on how many extra type of restriction I can make.

For example

```
restrictions(1,124,'post.courier',false)
```

But if do this,

```
restrictions(2,1322,'country','Greece')
```

the value field it's a different type.

My second thought was to use a field restrictions type TEXT and pass inside both values and restriction in a `JSON` format or `XML`

Another thought was to create separate tables for each kind,

[image]

and join them all, but it didn't seem proper.

What would be the best in my case?
Is there a better way I could design my DB?

Comment: Separate tables honestly makes the most sense from a DB design perspective. If you cram multiple data types into a restrictions table it will only lead to heartache. If you aren't going to process them in the database, only in the APP, it may make sense to have an xml column either in the products table or in a 1:1 related table that stores the unbounded restrictions for that product.

Comment: smells like an answer to me, @JNK

Comment: @MaxVernon I need to flesh it out more and don't have time currently. Feel free to turn it in to one, I'll upvote it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would it not be safe to assume that your products might have more than one restriction?

In that case, don't you need an intersection between product and restriction (type)?

Consider this ERD:

[image]

Note that restrictions are shown using an entity-sub-typing model.  You can keep distinct restriction value types appropriate to the kind of data that you require.  At the same time, the individual specific restriction types share a key space with the restriction header table.  That makes the intersection: `PRODUCT_RESTRICTION` easier to define and use.

There are different ways of doing it, but you'd probably want to consider including a *partitioning attribute* in the `RESTRICTION` table.

*Walter Mitty suggests:*

> If you want to model restrictions as a case of subtyping, there are
>   design patterns for this case.   There are two tags over in
>   StackOverflow where the info tab might help you: 
>   [single-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance) [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance)

*Joel Brown responds:*

The restriction model I have illustrated is one common way of implementing subtyping.  There are other variations.

Comment: Can you give me a link with more information about *partitioning attribute*?

Comment: @yannis - Hmmm, hard to find a really great link.  The terminology is what's used in James Martin's Information Engineering(TM) method.  Some others call it a _classifying attribute_.  The topic to read up is **Entity Subtyping** - this will cover the various ways that you could implement this model physically.  The point of the _partitioning attribute_ is to help enforce mutual exclusivity of subtypes.  Each subtype is associated with a particular data value in the partitioning attribute.